# List feature class returns nothing

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, feature-class

All I'm trying to do is list out the feature classes in a geodatabase. As far as I understand if you use arcpy.ListFeatureClasses, it should return a list of the features classes in that geodatabase. But I get nothing. I don't get None. I don't get []. Simply nothing is returned and the module acts like it's ready for the next command. I've checked and there is a gdb under that name, in that place, that does have feature classes in it. What am I missing here?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\gathr\\indonesia\\Sara\\VIIRS_Detections\\January2016.gdb"
arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

Comment: Is L a mapped drive? You might not have the path correct, if so. Instead of typing out the link, try navigating to your geodatabase in arcCatalog and dragging it in when you set your workspace. What you have should work if your path is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign it to a variable:

```
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

Then you can access the variable:

```
for fc in featureclasses:
 (do something)...
```

[Checkout the examples here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm):

Comment: @confused_coder if this has worked for you, please mark as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)